# Quicksort for array of objects fails

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, recursion, quicksort

I couldn't find the answer for this on Stack Overflow.

I have a function called `quickSort`:

```
function quickSort(array, prop) {
    if (array.length <= 1) return array;

    const pivot = array[0]; // I've tried array[0][prop] but it doesn't work
    const left = [];
    const right = [];

    for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i][prop] < pivot) {
            left.push(array[i]);
        } else {
            right.push(array[i]);
        }
    }

    return [...quickSort(left), pivot, ...quickSort(right)];
}
console.log(quickSort(data, 'motor'));
```

And I want sort this array of objects by `motor`:

```
let data = [
    {
        "color": "A",
        "door": 1,
        "wheel": 3,
        "year": 1963,
        "brand": "GMC",
        "sold": false,
        "owner": "Chalmers Boobyer",
        "motor": 2.6,
        "assembled": "20/08/2021"
    },
    {
        "color": "B",
        "door": 2,
        "wheel": 2,
        "year": 1980,
        "brand": "Ford",
        "sold": false,
        "owner": "Angelia Cromett",
        "motor": 2.5,
        "assembled": "02/05/2021"
    },
    {
        "color": "C",
        "door": 3,
        "wheel": 1,
        "year": 1999,
        "brand": "Audi",
        "sold": false,
        "owner": "Barth Pickring",
        "motor": 2.0,
        "assembled": "15/02/2021"
    },
    {
        "color": "D",
        "door": 4,
        "wheel": 1,
        "year": 2008,
        "brand": "Hyundai",
        "sold": true,
        "owner": "Aurore Soaper",
        "motor": 1.2,
        "assembled": "02/01/2019"
    }
];
```

Can someone explain how I can make `array[0][prop]` work?

Comment: `pivot` is an object, so you need to extract property `array[i][prop] < pivot[prop]` to compare

Comment: When you recursively call quickSort, you are not passing prop.

Comment: you are not passing the param `prop` in this line `return [...quickSort(left), pivot, ...quickSort(right)];`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I add but doesn't sort correctly

Comment: @James and K Galalem Guys, like this: return [...quickSort(left), pivot[prop], ...quickSort(right)] ?

Comment: So like this?     return [...quickSort(left, prop), pivot, ...quickSort(right, prop)]

Comment: @EduardoS Well, you'd also need to pass `prop` argument to the nested calls as the others have noted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest reading [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Adding a couple of strategic `console.log` statements before the comparison and at the start of the function to display the parameters is enough to show the problems. I did it for you this time, but you'll need to be able to debug your own programs if you want to make progress as a programmer.

A couple issues:

- Your recursive calls `quickSort(left)` and `quickSort(right)` are missing the second parameter `prop`.
- `array[i][prop] < pivot` is wrong if `pivot` is defined as `array[0]` because it compares different types. That should be `const pivot = array[0][prop]` as you attempted, but then you'd have to change your returned array to be

  ```js
  [...quickSort(left, prop), array[0], ...quickSort(right, prop)];
  ```

Here are the fixes applied:

```js
const quickSort = (array, prop) => {
  if (array.length <= 1) return array;

  // warning: bad pivot
  const pivot = array[0][prop];
  const left = []; // warning: allocations
  const right = [];

  for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i][prop] < pivot) {
      left.push(array[i]);
    }
    else {
      right.push(array[i]);
    }
  }

  return [
    ...quickSort(left, prop),
    array[0],
    ...quickSort(right, prop)
  ]; // warning: copies
};

const data = [
  {
    color: "A",
    door: 1,
    wheel: 3,
    year: 1963,
    brand: "GMC",
    sold: false,
    owner: "Chalmers Boobyer",
    motor: 2.6,
    assembled: "20/08/2021",
  },
  {
    color: "B",
    door: 2,
    wheel: 2,
    year: 1980,
    brand: "Ford",
    sold: false,
    owner: "Angelia Cromett",
    motor: 2.5,
    assembled: "02/05/2021",
  },
  {
    color: "C",
    door: 3,
    wheel: 1,
    year: 1999,
    brand: "Audi",
    sold: false,
    owner: "Barth Pickring",
    motor: 2.0,
    assembled: "15/02/2021",
  },
  {
    color: "D",
    door: 4,
    wheel: 1,
    year: 2008,
    brand: "Hyundai",
    sold: true,
    owner: "Aurore Soaper",
    motor: 1.2,
    assembled: "02/01/2019",
  },
];

console.log(quickSort(data, "motor"));
```

After the bug fixes, the sort still has issues:

- Recursive sorts shouldn't be allocating memory and copying arrays. Use indices to determine the recursive subarrays and swaps to move elements into the correct subarrays. This makes the code harder to write and read, but provides significant performance improvements.
- Choosing the pivot as 0 means you'll hit quadratic complexity and risk blowing the call stack on already-sorted data. [Research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Choice_of_pivot) and choose a better pivot-selection method.
- Specifying `prop` is pretty limited. Better to provide a callback similar to the built-in sort, so you can sort any objects rather than just a top-level prop.